# How to split newline from NSString in ObjectiveC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsstring

For my new project. i have loaded my csv file content as a NSString. 
First, i need to split this by newline, then split each line by comma.
How can i loop all this? Could you please help me?

**CSV Content**

"^GSPC",1403.36,"4/27/2012","4:32pm",+3.38,1400.19,1406.64,1397.31,574422720 "^IXIC",3069.20,"4/27/2012","5:30pm",+18.59,3060.34,3076.44,3043.30,0

**ViewController.m**

```
NSString* pathToFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"quotes" ofType: @"csv"];
NSString *fileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pathToFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
if (!fileString) {
    NSLog(@"Error reading file.");
}

NSArray *array = [fileString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

for(int i=0; i<[array count]; i++){      
    //
}
```

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32021712/how-to-split-a-string-by-new-lines-in-swift) for Swift answers

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Might want to look into `NSMutableArray`.

```
// grab your file
NSMutableArray *data = [[fileString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] mutableCopy];
for (int i = 0; i < [data count]; i++)
{
    [data replaceObjectAtIndex: i
                    withObject: [[data objectAtIndex: i] componentsSeparatedByString: @","]];
}
```

Relatedly, Dave DeLong has a proper library to address this need: https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser

Comment: Thank you pcperini. But, when i set this [data count] to my table numberOfRowsInSection, it is 5, not 2. please help me

Comment: @shebi check your text (csv) file within a Hex-Editor and see if it uses \r\n instead of \n.