# separate strings based on new lines iOS

Tags: ios

I'm wanting to create an app for iOS. In this app you input multiple commands into the input text view name myTextView. Then when you click generate all of those commands are then turned into one long command. So basically i need a way to separate the input text into an array. The string will be separated when there is a line break. This way I can put things like brackets and other things into the string. For example if I input:

say hi
say bye

that would be one string but would be turned into [say hi,time:10s] [say bye,time:10s]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370516/how-to-split-newline-from-nsstring-in-objectivec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this?

```
NSArray *commands = [inputString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the documentation of `NSString`
[here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString:)

And you will find this useful method:

```
 - (NSArray<NSString *> *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator
```

This method will return an `NSArray` of strings separated by input `NSString` which you will pass the `@"\n"`.

Comment: Thanks! but i managed to solve it by using this method: let fullName: String = myTextView.text;
        let fullNameArr = fullName.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
        let i = fullNameArr.count
        var c = 0
        while c < i && i != 0 {
        OutputView.hidden = false;
        OutputView.text = OutputView.text + fullNameArr[c]
        c = i + 1